# Windows batch: in a string, how to add one spaces between characters?

Tags: windows, batch-file

in a batch I have %cd% that is a path, for example c:\docu
I need to generate in a new enviroment variable     c : \ d o c u
  How can I do? thanks

Comment: thanks, I'm already in in a batch file. in the middle of the code I have %cd% that is a path, I have to adapt the code so that %cd% become with spaces, I have try your code but seems don't work

Answer (score 0):

Make a bat file called AddSpace.bat:

#### AddSpace.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set v=%*
set var=
set /a l=0
:loop
set c=!v:~%l%,1!
if "%c%"=="" goto end
set "var=%var%%c% "
set /a l+=1
goto loop
:end
Echo %var%
:: You can do whatever you want with the variable here.
endlocal
```

#### Use

```
C:\>>AddSpace.bat abcdef
a b c d e f

C:\>>AddSpace.bat C:\Program Files
C : \ P r o g r a m   F i l e s

C:\>>AddSpace.bat Hi This Message Has Spaces
H i   T h i s   M e s s a g e   H a s   S p a c e s

C:\>>AddSpace.bat Lots of Spaces here      -
L o t s   o f   S p a c e s   h e r e             -

C:\>>AddSpace.bat C:\docu
C : \ d o c u

C:\>>
```

**NB** As you can see, it will also double spaces. This is easy to fix, simply add:

```
if "%c%"==" " goto loop
```

just after `if "%c%"=="" goto end`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off



call :strlen0 cd len

echo %len%

set "final="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 for /l %%# in (0,1,%len%) do (
    set "letter_with_space=!cd:~%%#,1! "
    set final=!final!!letter_with_space!
 )
endlocal && (
    set "final=%final%"
)

echo %final%

exit /b 0
:strlen0  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b
```

It's done over `%cd%` as this is what you requested but it can be done over any variable.`strlen` subroutine is taken from here : http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=424